# Clash between splitbib and hyperref

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, subdividing, splitbib

When I use the `splitbib` package, the anchors for the citations produced by `hyperref` seem to disappear. I have some example code to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{splitbib}

\begin{document}
We cite~\cite{entry1,entry3,entry4,entry5}.

\clearpage
\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{entry1} This is the first entry.

\bibitem{entry3} This is the third entry.

\bibitem{entry4} This is the fourth one.

\bibitem{entry5} This is the last one.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

If the `splitbib` package is commented out, then the hyperlinks work as expected, i.e., clicking on `[1]` will take you to the next page. If the `splitbib` package is included, the link no longer works. Also, if you change the order of the two packages, it won't even compile.

My ultimate goal is to have a bibliography with a two categories ("Good Stuff" and "Everything Else") and then to have the "Good Stuff" split into several subcategories. I know many folks have suggested `biblatex`, but it's hard to figure out how to use the system. If someone can give me an `biblatex` example of what I ultimately need, that would also suffice to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `biblatex` solution using the "category" feature -- assign bibentries to categories within your main `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{goodA}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{goodB}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{else}
\addtocategory{goodA}{A01,K11}
\addtocategory{goodB}{B02}
\addtocategory{else}{C03}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@misc{K11,
  author = {Kuthor, K.},
  year = {2011},
  title = {Kilo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02,C03}. Some more text \autocite{K11}.

\printbibheading[title={Good Stuff}]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,category=goodA,title={Good Stuff, category~A}]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,category=goodB,title={Good Stuff, category~B}]

\printbibliography[category=else,title={Everything Else}]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you may add the special `keywords` field to your `.bib` file :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords = {goodA},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  keywords = {goodB},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  keywords = {else},
}
@misc{K11,
  author = {Kuthor, K.},
  year = {2011},
  title = {Kilo},
  keywords = {goodA},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02,C03}. Some more text \autocite{K11}.

\printbibheading[title={Good Stuff}]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword=goodA,title={Good Stuff, category~A}]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword=goodB,title={Good Stuff, category~B}]

\printbibliography[keyword=else,title={Everything Else}]

\end{document}
```

The identical output for both examples (EDIT: now also demonstrating the use of `hyperref`):

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks very much. I have another question: how do I convince biblatex to number things in order in the bibliography. Currently they are numbered in alphabetical author order, rather than first by category and then by alphabetical order. I am using the first version of the code, i.e., where I declare the category in the latex code rather than the bib database. Thanks in advance for any further help.

Comment: I found the answer --- add defernumbers=true in the options for the biblatex package.

Comment: @user937840 Indeed. I updated my example to be more instructive.